# Hide UI Taxonomies that are empty - Search & Filter Pro

Tags: wordpress

I am using S&F Prowith WooCommerce. I have filtering in the shop which is working great, however I want to hide filters that are empty.

So for example, if I’m in the T-Shirts category, the filtering taxonomy type **“Flavour”** wouldn’t return any products. At the moment it displays the filter in the **li**, with a **h4** title.

Is it possible to add a class to the filter **li**, such as “**empty**” so I can target with CSS? Because at the moment there are titles appearing with no filter options below as they’re not applicable.

Kind regards
Ayaz Ahmad

Comment: There should be a "Hide empty" right below "display count" on your field.

Comment: I checked the Hide Empty but the Labels don't. Only their options hide.

Comment: Please check this link: https://afaqsaleem.shop/product-category/spa/accessoires